# Constraints of $n$-dimensional cylinder inside sphere

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functional-analysis, optimization, dimensional-analysis

In three dimensions, maximising volume of cylinder inside a sphere (denote $B_3(R)$ , wo.l.o.g centered around the origin) is straightforward. We get constraints to the radius of the cylinder via good ol' Pythagorean:
$$r^2 + \left (\frac{h}{2}\right )^2 = R^2.\tag{1} $$

How does one make sense of general constraints in $\mathbb R^n$? For instance, if we consider a four dimensional cylinder in a $B_4(R)$, the base of the cylinder is now a sphere $B_3(r)$ (we get the $4$-dimensional volume if we multiply by height).

If it is safe to assume that maximal cylinder is also centered around the origin, what would the constraints on $r$ (the radius of the base) look like?

Relevant formulae for volume of $n$-balls can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball), so I'm not worried about the optimisation process itself.

---

The following intuition might be as wrong as wrong gets, but here goes.

For instance, if we look at the projection for $n=3$, we get $(1)$. For $n=4$, the projection would be a $B_3(R)$ with the maximal cylinder inside it, so we project it further and the constraints remain the same. Assume the constraint $(1)$ holds, in general.

The volume $V_{n+1}^C$ of the cylinder would be
$$V_{n+1}^C = V_{B_n(r)}\cdot h = \frac{\pi ^{n/2}\cdot r^nh}{\Gamma (1+n/2)} := C_n \cdot r^nh. $$
With the constraint applied we have
$$r^n = \left (R^2 - \frac{h^2}{4}\right )^{n/2}. $$
Thus
$$V_{n+1}^C(h) = C_n h\left (R^2 - \frac{h^2}{4}\right )^{n/2} $$
This yields the maximal height of
$$h_m = \frac{2R}{\sqrt{n+1}}, $$
which agrees with the maximal height for three dimensional case! (curiously, the volume shrinks to zero as $n$ gets larger )

Is this inductive process of taking projections until we reach the case $n=2$ justified?

---

If the 'size' of the object gets smaller and smaller as $n$ increases, by taking projections the 'shadow' of the object becomes larger?!

---

I think this works as follows. In $n+1$-dimensional case the points in the sphere can be characterised as follows:
$$x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n, H)\qquad \|x\|\leq R $$
When we take the projection, we observe the set of points of dimension $n$:
$$\bar{x} = (x_1,\ldots , x_{n-1},H) $$
The projection of $B_{n+1}(R)$ still has radius $R$ thus
$$x_1^2+\ldots + x_{n-1}^2 + H^2 \leq R^2 $$
So, we would necessarely arrive at $(1)$.

---

Feel free to change tags to more adequate ones.

Comment: related, but focused on computation not justification https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924339/maximizing-hyper-cylinder-volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should be able to argue by induction on the dimension. Taking projection of dimension 3 case (with respect to anything other than than the height component - we don' want two circles as projection in 2 dimensions).

So, if the center of cylinder is the center of sphere for dimension $k$, then taking any non-height-component-projection of the $k+1$ dimensional case, the necessary condition (1) is preserved.

I don't know how to formalise this idea or if it's correct, though.